# Exploratory Factor Analysis - Method Generating Factor Scores

Tags: factor-analysis

I want to understand the differences between different methods of generating factor scores in exploratory factor analysis, namely Regression method, Bartlett scores and Anderson-Rubin method.

I found a reference here (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_24.0.0/spss/base/idh_fact_sco.html) but I dont understand what they say.

Can someone kindly explain to a non stat-savvy person like me please? Thank you very much.

Comment: This paper might be useful: https://pareonline.net/getvn.asp?v=14&n=20